# Azure Web App can't access the Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I have a Web API which accesses an Azure Storage Account, in local development/test all works fine, however when I published my Web API to Azure, my API stopped working raising the Authorization Error below:

```
2021-10-24T10:31:31.511791298Z: [INFO]  [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: DocumentUploader.Controllers.DocumentController[1001]
2021-10-24T10:31:31.511811800Z: [INFO]        POST : Internal Error. Error message : This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
2021-10-24T10:31:31.511846903Z: [INFO]        RequestId:db008379-e01a-0021-59c2-c84447000000
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512839496Z: [INFO]        Time:2021-10-24T10:31:31.5024279Z
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512866599Z: [INFO]        Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512871599Z: [INFO]        ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512883200Z: [INFO]        
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512886901Z: [INFO]        Content:
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512890801Z: [INFO]        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512895702Z: [INFO]        RequestId:db008379-e01a-0021-59c2-c84447000000
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512899402Z: [INFO]        Time:2021-10-24T10:31:31.5024279Z</Message></Error>
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512903302Z: [INFO]        
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512906803Z: [INFO]        Headers:
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512910403Z: [INFO]        Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512913903Z: [INFO]        x-ms-request-id: db008379-e01a-0021-59c2-c84447000000
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512917504Z: [INFO]        x-ms-client-request-id: 328261a6-0b66-4526-9425-06f1cdb07bb8
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512921104Z: [INFO]        x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationFailure
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512924704Z: [INFO]        Date: Sun, 24 Oct 2021 10:31:31 GMT
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512928305Z: [INFO]        Content-Length: 246
2021-10-24T10:31:31.512931805Z: [INFO]        Content-Type: application/xml
```

I believe to be a problem with firewall/networking, I read this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#manage-exceptions, therefore I added the exceptions to allow the Web API's public IP access to the storage.

The public IPs, I found on the Web API networking page, therefore I added these as exceptions in the Storage...

Any clue why my web API can't access the storage?

Comment: By the way, this is a test environment, I don't want to upgrade the plan.

Answer (score 0):

Go the the properties of your App Service and copy all the **outbound IP addresses** in the networking tile of your Storage Account to whitelist them.

You can enable **"Allow trusted Microsoft Services"** to give access for your App Service to the Storage Account. There are [two modes of trusted access for Microsoft services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-to-trusted-azure-services):

- Trusted access for resources registered in your subscription
- Trusted access based on system-assigned managed identity

If you are using a App Service Plan that has a Standard, Premium, or Isolated tier, you can put your App Service in a virtual network. Then, you would add your VNET your Storage Account networking configuration.

Comment: I did it, but still facing same error. Actually I added the CIDRs to test, before adding IP by IP. My plan is the Free one, as I'm doing a demo only, Any other suggestion?

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look at granting access to trusted Azure services.

Comment: Many thanks, I am working on it, but it seems weird that the API works fine in my laptop by adding my laptop IP as exception, but I can't do the same to allow the API work from Web App, because the access is blocked although I added the outbound IPs as exception.

Comment: Many thanks. I scaled up to Standard. I followed up the VNET configuration approach.